# Not sure how to write processed texts to a new directory with the original filename

Tags: python

I am able to write single files to a different directory but when I try to iterate through all the files in the directory, I get stuck with how to write the processed files.

I have looked at examples for using a for loop with glob and os modules, but I am not able to make it work for my particular purpose. I can include the code where the processing occurs if that is helpful.

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('*.txt')):

with open(filename,'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
    words = file.read()

processedwords = lemmatize_words(words)

file = open(filename, 'w')
file.write(processedwords)
```

I am expecting the files to write to the directory. This is returning a list. I need the lemmatized words to be saved as their original file name.

```
   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python Assignments>python readwrite.py
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "readwrite.py", line 88, in <module>
   file.write(processedwords)
   TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

Comment: I have this one figured out now. I just changed the last line to file.write(str(lemmas))

Answer (score 0):

Let me correct your code

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('*.txt')):

with open(filename,'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
    words = file.read()

processedwords = str(lemmatize_words(words)) #change class of lemmatize_words(words)

file = open(filename, 'w')
file.write(processedwords)
```

The problem is `lemmatize_words(words)` return a non-string value, so you must change it to string value using `str` class. Since `processedwords` is not a string type